# Does conditional stationarity of $X_t$ imply that $\lim_{j\to \infty} \mathbb{E}_t[X_{t+j}]$ exists?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

Let $X_t$ be univariate stochastic process. Assume $X_t$ is conditionally stationary that is for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and time indices $t_1,\ldots, t_{n+1}$, $t_{i}<t_{i+1}$ and shift $\tau$

$$F(X_{t_{n+1}}|X_{t_{1}}\ldots,X_{t_{n}})=F(X_{t_{n+1+\tau}}|X_{t_{1}+\tau}\ldots,X_{t_{n}+\tau}),$$

where $F$ is the distribution function. Assume the conditional mean function exists so that

$$\mathbb{E}(X_{t_{n+1}}|X_{t_{1}}\ldots,X_{t_{n}})=\mathbb{E}(X_{t_{n+1+\tau}}|X_{t_{1}+\tau}\ldots,X_{t_{n}+\tau}),$$

Does this imply that $\lim_{j\to \infty} \mathbb{E}_t[X_{t+j}]$ exists? If not can we add some further assumption to guarantee the limit exists?

Comment: This is related to my question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736605/does-stationarity-of-x-t-imply-that-lim-j-to-infty-mathbbe-tx-tj

Comment: I think the same counter example in the last post works here-- that Gaussian process is strictly stationary, and hence conditionally stationary. Further conditions that you might add to make it true would be something like "weak dependence", e.g. clearly this holds if the sequence has a finite range of dependence.

Comment: @LostStatistician18 Thanks! You seem correct. Could you elaborate why weak dependence might be the sufficient condition? Or do you know a good source about this?

Comment: Intuitively if the variables $X_{t+j}$ and $X_t$ are basically independent for large $j$, then the limit will be constant and equal to the overall mean of the process. One assumption that would imply this is to just assume the variables are eventually independent, i.e. a finite range of dependence. Another would be something like $\alpha$ mixing; maybe have a look at that.